# How to define hololens CoordinateSystem in c#?

Tags: c#, augmented-reality, hololens

I´m trying to use `TryCreateRelativeTo(SpatialCoordinateSystem coordinateSystem, Vector3 position)` method from hololens. How can I define a new SpatialCoordinateSystem variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SpatialLocator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.perception.spatial.spatiallocator) class to create a Frame Of Reference (eg Head locked, stationary..).

That FrameOfReference has a [SpatialCoordinateSystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.perception.spatial.spatialstationaryframeofreference.coordinatesystem#Windows_Perception_Spatial_SpatialStationaryFrameOfReference_CoordinateSystem) property.

A good example of using these classes is included in the [Tag-along sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/HolographicTagAlong).